# ObervableObject being init multiple time, and not refreshing my view

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui-navigationlink, swiftui

I have a structure like this:

```swift
contentView {
    navigationView {
        foreach {
            NavigationLink(ViewA(id: id))
        }
    }
}
```

```swift
/// where ViewA contains an request trigger when it appears
struct ViewA: View {

    @State var filterString: String = ""

    var id: String!
    @ObservedObject var model: ListObj = ListObj()

    init(id: String) {
        self.id = id
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            SearchBarView(searchText: $filterString)
            List {
                ForEach(model.items.filter({ filterString.isEmpty || $0.id.contains(filterString) || $0.name.contains(filterString)  }), id: \.id) { item in
                    NavigationLink(destination: ViewB(id: item.id)) {
                        VStack {
                            Text("\(item.name) ")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        }
        .onAppear {
            self.model.getListObj(id: self.id) //api request, fill data and call objectWillChange.send()
        }
    }
}
```

`ViewB` has the same code as `ViewA`: It receives an id, stores and requests an API to collect data.

But the `viewB` list is not being refreshed.

I also noticed that `viewB`'s `model` property

```swift
@ObservedObject var model: model = model()
```

was instantiated multiple times.

Debugging, I found that every navigationLink instantiates its destination even before it is triggered. That's not a problem usually, but in my case i feel like the `ViewB` model is being instantiated 2 times, and my `onAppear` call the wrong one, reason why `self.objectWillChange.send()` not refreshing my view.

Comment: Fernand, all your trouble went from the fact that your model is dependent on the fact, if some View appear ... even though if you finally will find some "solution", it will be very fragile! change your approach as soon, as possible.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If your `@ObservedObject` is being initialized multiple times, it is because the owner of the object is refreshed and recreated every time it has state changes. Try to use `@StateObject` if your app is iOS 14 and above. It prevents the object from being recreated when the view refreshes.
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/stateobject

> When a view creates its own @ObservedObject instance it is recreated
> every time a view is discarded and redrawn. On the contrary a @State
> variable will keep its value when a view is redrawn. A @StateObject is
> a combination of @ObservedObject and @State - the instance of the
> ViewModel will be kept and reused even after a view is discarded and
> redrawn

[What is the difference between ObservedObject and StateObject in SwiftUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62544115/what-is-the-difference-between-observedobject-and-stateobject-in-swiftui)

Comment: Hello there, just a small explanation: The previous accepted answer from @arsenius was the needed one because StateObject was not available. Both solution are good  i prioritised this solution only because i don't want conduct other people to use a 'workaround' solution that should be deprecated within language & iOS version adoption, note that the most important here is : StateObject is available only for iOS 14 and above

Answer (score 13):

There are two issues here:

1. SwiftUI uses value types that that get initialized over and over again each pass through `body`.
2. Related to #1, `NavigationLink` is not lazy.

#### #1

A new `ListObj` gets instantiated every time you call `ViewA.init(...)`.  `ObservedObject` **does not** work the same as `@State` where SwiftUI keeps careful track of it for you throughout the onscreen lifecycle.  SwiftUI assumes that ultimate ownership of an `@ObservedObject` exists at some level above the `View` it's used in.

In other words, you should almost always avoid things like `@ObservedObject var myObject = MyObservableObject()`.

(Note, even if you did `@State var model = ListObj()` it would be instantiated every time.  But because it's `@State` SwiftUI will replace the new instance with the original before `body` gets called.)

### #2

In addition to this, `NavigationLink` is not lazy.  Each time you instantiate that `NavigationLink` you pass a newly instantiated `ViewA`, which instantiates your `ListObj`.

So for starters, one thing you can do is make a `LazyView` to delay instantiation until `NavigationLink.destination.body` actually gets called:

```swift
// Use this to delay instantiation when using `NavigationLink`, etc...
struct LazyView<Content: View>: View {
    var content: () -> Content
    var body: some View {
        self.content()
    }
}
```

Now you can do `NavigationLink(destination: LazyView { ViewA() })` and instantiation of `ViewA` will be deferred until the `destination` is actually shown.

Simply using `LazyView` will fix your current problem **as long as it's the top view in the hierarchy**, like it is when you push it in a `NavigationView` or if you present it.

However, this is where @user3441734's comment comes in.  What you really need to do is keep ownership of `model` somewhere outside of your `View` because of what was explained in #1.

Comment: Thanks a lot, i've seen model = model() in lot of tutorial, was not expecting that.