# Using view models in SwiftUI without allocation overhead

Tags: ios, swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink, ios-navigationview, swiftui-navigationview

#### Using View Models in *SwiftUI*

For a clean separation of concerns, I want to use my *SwiftUI* views with view models.

I have two views, a `ListView` and a `DetailView` where the first pushes the latter when any list item is tapped – a classic navigation view.

I define a `viewModel` property on my `DetailView` as follows and mark it as an observed object in order to update the view when any of its published properties change:

```
struct DetailView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: DetailViewModel

    var body: some View { 
        Text(viewModel.text)
    }
}
```

This approach requires me to pass a `viewModel` to the `DetailView`'s initializer when I create the view inside the `ListView`:

```
struct ListView: View {
    let animals = ["", "", "", "", ""]

    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(animals, id: \.self) { animal in
                NavigationLink(
                    destination: DetailView(viewModel: DetailViewModel(text: animal))
                ) {
                    Text(animal)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

where `DetailViewModel` here is simply defined as follows:

```
class DetailViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var text: String
}
```

(A view model is certainly over-engineered here, but it's just for the sake of explaining the problem.)

#### ⚡️ The Problem

As the destination views for all navigations links are created each time the list view's `body` is updated, so are the respective view models. That's not much of a problem for a simple view model as shown above, but it certainly becomes a problem with more complex real-world view models. For example, a view model might instantiate other classes that are rather expensive to initialize. This would be done at the time of showing the `ListView` **for each and every `DetailView` (model)** – regardless of whether it's ever going to be shown (needed) or not.

Thus, it seems to me like an anti-pattern to create view models inside the bodies of other views. Still, it is the most common practice I've seen in code examples and articles across the Internet.

#### ❓ My Question

Is there a way to keep a *SwiftUI* view from instantiating the destinations views of `NavigationLink`s immediately? Or is there a way to create view models for view to be used as navigation link destinations outside of a view's `body`?

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/60295011/12299030?

Comment: Yup, the `LazyView` definitely solves the problem of instantiating all destination views and their view models too early. Thanks for that reference!

However, it still feels a bit more like a workaround to me. I think, in general, a view model for the next view should not be instantiated inside a _SwiftUI_ view's body, as there is also the ownership issue mentioned in the answer you linked. But I understand that this is more of an architectural question...

Comment: I think you can use a StateObject to do what you need to do: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/stateobject. Unrelated to the question I'd recommend using https://github.com/pointfreeco/swift-composable-architecture for building SwiftUI apps as it fixes a lot of problems that vanilla SwiftUI has such as this one

Comment: What approach you end up going with? Creating a view model for a detail view should be so difficult.. unless i'm really missing something